# How to save output of multiple queries under single JSON file in appended mode using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have 5 queries like below:

```
select * from table1  
select * from table2  
select * from table3  
select * from table4  
select * from table5
```

Now, what I want is I have to execute these queries in the sequential fashion and then keep on storing the output in the `single JSON` file in the `appended` mode. I wrote the below code but it stores the output for each query in `different part files` instead of one.
Below is my code:

```
def store(jobEntity: JobDetails, jobRunId: Int): Unit = {
    UDFUtil.registerUdfFunctions()
    var outputTableName: String = null
    val jobQueryMap = jobEntity.jobQueryList.map(jobQuery => (jobQuery.sequenceId, jobQuery))
    val sortedQueries = scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap(jobQueryMap.toSeq: _*).toMap
    LOGGER.debug("sortedQueries ===>" + sortedQueries)
    try {
      outputTableName = jobEntity.destinationEntity
      var resultDF: DataFrame = null
      sortedQueries.values.foreach(jobQuery => {
        LOGGER.debug(s"jobQuery.query ===> ${jobQuery.query}")
        resultDF = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.sqlContext.sql(jobQuery.query)

        if (jobQuery.partitionColumn != null && !jobQuery.partitionColumn.trim.isEmpty) {
          resultDF = resultDF.repartition(jobQuery.partitionColumn.split(",").map(col): _*)
        }
        if (jobQuery.isKeepInMemory) {
          resultDF = resultDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
        }
        if (jobQuery.isCheckpointEnabled) {
          val checkpointDir = ApplicationConfig.getAppConfig(JobConstants.CHECKPOINT_DIR)
          val fs = FileSystem.get(new Storage(JsonUtil.toMap[String](jobEntity.sourceConnection)).asHadoopConfig())
          val path = new Path(checkpointDir)
          if (!fs.exists(path)) {
            fs.mkdirs(path)
          }
          resultDF.explain(true)
          SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(checkpointDir)
          resultDF = resultDF.checkpoint
        }
        resultDF = {
          if (jobQuery.isBroadCast) {
            import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
            broadcast(resultDF)
          } else
            resultDF
        }
        tempViewsList.+=(jobQuery.queryAliasName)
        resultDF.createOrReplaceTempView(jobQuery.queryAliasName)
        //      resultDF.explain(true)
        val map: Map[String, String] = JsonUtil.toMap[String](jobEntity.sinkConnection)
        LOGGER.debug("sink details :: " + map)
        if (resultDF != null && !resultDF.take(1).isEmpty) {
          resultDF.show(false)
          val sinkDetails = new Storage(JsonUtil.toMap[String](jobEntity.sinkConnection))
          val path = sinkDetails.basePath + File.separator + jobEntity.destinationEntity
          println("path::: " + path)
          resultDF.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json(path)
        }
      }
      )
```

Just ignore the other things(`Checkpointing`, `Logging`, `Auditing`) that I am doing in this method along with reading and writing.

Comment: do they all have same schema? If so Why don't you just union all the datframe?

Comment: No, they have different schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below example as a reference for your problem.

I have three tables with `Json` data (***with different schema***) as below:

1. `table1` --> Personal Data Table
2. `table2` --> Company Data Table
3. `table3` --> Salary Data Table

I am reading these three tables one by one in the sequential mode as per your requirement and doing few transformations over data (exploding Json array Column) with the help of List `TableColList` which contains Array column Name corresponding to table with a semicolon (":") separator.

`OutDFList` is the list of all transformed DataFrames.

At the end, I am reducing all DataFrames from `OutDFList` into a single dataframe and writing it into one `JSON` file.

> ****Note:** I have used join to reduced all DataFrames, You can also use**
> **union(if have same columns) or else as per requirement.**

Check below code:

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from table1").printSchema
root
 |-- Personal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- DOB: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EmpID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)


scala> spark.sql("select * from table2").printSchema
root
 |-- Company: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- EmpID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- JoinDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Project: string (nullable = true)


scala> spark.sql("select * from table3").printSchema
root
 |-- Salary: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- EmpID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Monthly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Yearly: string (nullable = true)

scala> val TableColList = List("table1:Personal", "table2:Company", "table3:Salary")
TableColList: List[String] = List(table1:Personal, table2:Company, table3:Salary)


scala>  val OutDFList = TableColList.map{ X =>
     |  val table = X.split(":")(0)
     |  val arrayColumn = X.split(":")(1)
     |  val df = spark.sql(s"""SELECT * FROM """ + table).select(explode(col(arrayColumn)) as "data").select("data.*")
     | df}
OutDFList: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = List([DOB: string, EmpID: string ... 1 more field], [EmpID: string, JoinDate: string ... 1 more field], [EmpID: string, Monthly: string ... 1 more field])

scala> val FinalOutDF  = OutDFList.reduce((df1, df2) => df1.join(df2, "EmpID"))
FinalOutDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [EmpID: string, DOB: string ... 5 more fields]

scala> FinalOutDF.printSchema
root
 |-- EmpID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DOB: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- JoinDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Project: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Monthly: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Yearly: string (nullable = true)


scala> FinalOutDF.write.json("/FinalJsonOut")
```

Comment: Yeah. This is what I needed. Thanks to @Nikk

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you need to union all the schemas:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = sc.parallelize(List(
  (42, 11),
  (43, 21)
)).toDF("foo", "bar")

val df2 = sc.parallelize(List(
  (44, true, 1.0),
  (45, false, 3.0)
)).toDF("foo", "foo0", "foo1")

val cols1 = df1.columns.toSet
val cols2 = df2.columns.toSet
val total = cols1 ++ cols2 // union

def expr(myCols: Set[String], allCols: Set[String]) = {
  allCols.toList.map(x => x match {
    case x if myCols.contains(x) => col(x)
    case _ => lit(null).as(x)
  })
}

val total = df1.select(expr(cols1, total):_*).unionAll(df2.select(expr(cols2, total):_*))

total.show()
```

And obvs save to the single JSON file:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').json("/some/path")
```

**UPD**

If you are not using DFs, just come along with plain SQL queries (writing to single file remains the same - `coalesce(1)` or `repartition(1)`):

```
spark.sql(
  """
    |SELECT id, name
    |FROM (
    | SELECT first.id, first.name, FROM first
    | UNION
    | SELECT second.id, second.name FROM second
    | ORDER BY second.name
    | ) t
  """.stripMargin).show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Artem. Here, in my problem I dont have different dfs so how can I use union ? Also under the directory I need the data under one file for which I cannot see any part in your code

Comment: For having single file use `coalesce(1)` or `repartition(1)`.  If you are trying to avoid using DFs just make union in plain SQL - check UPD section.

Comment: I tried that. Actually 5 different queries create 5 different files irrespective of  repartition or coalesce

Comment: @Debuggerrr try to run the join in a single query (see UPD section) and its result write to the disk with `coalesce(1)`, you would deal only with one DF.